# Keep Looping until inputs are available in java

Tags: java, c++, loops

If I don't know the input size already, what is the the way to keep iterating in a loop until it is available, in JAVA. In C++ it can be done as following.

```
int main(){
    int val;
    while(cin >> val){
           //do stuff
    } 
}
```

What is the way to do similar thing(as above) in java

Thanks in Advance.
Shantanu

Comment: if i understand correctly what u r asking is "how to keep iterating a loop until a previously declared variable is initialized by the user through command-line??" right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the following thing.

```
    long val;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String temp = sc.next().trim();

        val = Long.parseLong(temp);
        // do stuff
    }
```

Comment: your code is throwing following exception. Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Unknown Source)

Comment: instead of sc.nextLong() you should use nextXXX() that what you want to read

Comment: @shem. I was trying to read long only.   Edited solution is working(taking input as string then converting it in long).   Thanks.

Comment: in that case you should use this:Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      while (sc.hasNextLong()) {
       val = sc.nextLong();
      }

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use Scanner.

```
long val;
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
while (sc.hasNextLong() ) {
    val = sc.nextLong();
    // do stuff
}
```

This is equivalent to the cpp code you provided. But not exactly what you asked for. It will loop as long as there are legal inputs in the read string.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your specific requirement use the methods in the Scanner class. This one reads an entire line. Which means user have to press enter in most systems.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String str=new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not implement busy loops. You will probably prefer to use streams. Method `read()` of stream is blocked until the data arrives, so your code will be simple without busy loops and work exactly as you want:

```
while ( in.read() != -1) {
   // do your stuff
}
```

or even better using buffers:

```
byte[] buf = new buf[MAX_SIZE]
while ( in.read(buf) != -1) {
   // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Alex. Could you please initialize **in** variable also. I have tried your first loop by initializing in as `InputStream in = System.in;` and simply inserted one print statement inside while loop. Now it is printing three time whenever i am hitting enter.

Answer (score 0):

i believe the best way to serve your purpose is via multithreading where one thread will wait for the input from user and let the other thread know when it receives one. In the mean time the other thread will keep iterating through the loop.